# Django Channels Invalid Syntax

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-channels

I am trying to work with Django Channels. Every time I try to run manage.py, I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daphne/server.py", line 192
    async def handle_reply(self, protocol, message):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have installed all the necessary components for Channels to work.

Comment: remove async at the start of the line

Comment: https://github.com/django/daphne/issues/155 please check daphne version

Comment: It's advisable at least pass crash course for the language and learn at least BASIC syntax to avoid questions like above.

Comment: @Denis `async def` is perfectly valid syntax - on Python 3.5+, which is required for Channels. Please learn the basics of the language yourself before criticising.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daphne/server.py" Thank you, opinion of ADHD people is very important for us.

Comment: @Denis I have no idea what any of that comment means. Why did you show the path to the file? It's in the question, and it's part of Daphne so I have no idea why you think it is invalid syntax or why OP should edit it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daphne/server.py" -> python2.7. Case is closed.

Comment: @Denis what case? What on earth are you talking about? Yes, OP is using a version of Python that is incompatible with Channels 2. What does that have to do with your initial rude comment about OP learning basic syntax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165325/discussion-between-denis-and-daniel-roseman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems You are using django channels 2.0.2, which requires python version >= 3.5:

http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/one-to-two.html

I recommend to use python 3 virtualenv:

1. Check Your python version by running *python3* command, for sure.
2. Create python3 virtualenv: *virtualenv -p python3 envname*
3. Instal necessary packages (channels, etc..).
4. If You have trouble installing channels, python3-dev package is
   probably missing.